# Efficiently moving large sets of data between SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a rather large (many gigabytes) table of data in SQL Server that I wish to move to a table in another database on the same server.

The tables are the same layout.

What would be the most effecient way of going about doing this?

This is a one off operation so no automation is required.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a one-off operation, why care about *top* efficiency so much?

```
SELECT * INTO OtherDatabase..NewTable FROM ThisDatabase..OldTable
```

or

```
INSERT OtherDatabase..NewTable
SELECT * FROM ThisDatabase..OldTable
```

...and let it run over night. I would dare to say that using SELECT/INSERT INTO on the same server is not far from the best efficiency you can get anyway.

Comment: You make a valid point.  I guess I am just too programmed to do things the 'right way'.  Query is running as I type!

Comment: consider the BULK INSERT instead of insert.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: what if I want to move data from one database to another on different servers?

Comment: @Adi Look up "linked servers". The rest of the approach is the same.

Comment: There will be transaction log growth doing it this way. Could bring your server to its knees should it exceed disk space. Being that it is all one giant transaction you cant just stop it in the middle w/o incurring a large transaction rollback. For Large tables this is NOT the way to go.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 That's a good point. Do you have a better suggestion as well?

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the "SQL Import and Export Wizard" found under "Management" in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Tomalak's answer.

You might want to temporarily put your target database into bulk-logged recovery mode before executing a 'select into' to stop the log file exploding...

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL Server 7 or 2000 look at Data Transformation Services (DTS). For SQL 2005 and 2008 look at SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely put the target DB into bulk-logged mode. This will minimally log the operation and speed it up.